# How to group twice?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'd like to know how to group twice in a data set. I must answer the following question: "For each state, which municipalities have the lowest and the highest infections and death rates?". This question is part of a homework (https://github.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/blob/master/assignments/hw6.Rmd) and I don't know how to do it. I've tried to use top_n, but I am not sure if this is the best way.

I wanted to generate a data set in which, for each state, there were four municipalities (two with the highest rates of infection and death from coronavirus and two with the smallest). This is what a have done so far:

```
library(tidyverse)

brazilcorona <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/data sets/brazilcorona.csv")

brazilcorona_hl_rates <- select(brazilcorona, (estado:emAcompanhamentoNovos)) %>%
  filter(data >= "2020-05-15") %>%
  subset(!(coduf == 76)) %>%
  mutate(av_inf = (casosAcumulado/populacaoTCU2019)*100000,
         av_dth = (obitosAcumulado/populacaoTCU2019)*100000)

brazilcorona_hilow_rates <- brazilcorona_hl_rates %>%
  group_by(estado) %>%
  summarize(top_dth = top_n(1, av_dth))
```

Comment: Look into using `arrange` and `slice` from the tidyverse. You can arrange by rates of infection or death, group by estado, and then use slice to get the first couple and last couple observations for each estado... I think there is a function called n() to figure out the index of the last observation per group.

Comment: That data link doesn't work for me (to fill `brazilcorona`), I found it at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/brazilcorona.csv. I cannot see how your code is working, as the link is a 404 in my browser (R notwithstanding).

Comment: This sounds like *"group **once** by `estado` and `municipio`"* and them *"summarise two statistics"*. Since one of the columns is accumulating, I think Nova's recommendation for `arrange` and `slice` can work, but you still need to `group_by(estado)` to start it. For instance, if we wanted to know by-state (instead of municipality), we might start with `brazilcorona %>% select(estado, casosAcumulado, obitosAcumulado) %>% group_by(estado) %>% summarize_all(~ max(.))` (`max` since both stats are accumulating). This doesn't give you the answer, but you can easily extend this.

Answer (score 0):

In my example, I find two cities per state with the maximum and minimum values for the column "obitosAcumulado", but to solve your problem you should simply change it to the column containing the information you want to extract the information from.

```
rm(list=ls())
brazilcorona <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/brazilcorona.csv")
#
#remove NA's from municipios
brazilcorona<-brazilcorona[!is.na(brazilcorona$municipio),]
#here I am gonna use the column "obitosAcumulado" but you should use the one you want
brazilcorona$obitosAcumulado<-as.numeric(brazilcorona$obitosAcumulado)
states<-as.list(unique(brazilcorona$estado))
result<-lapply(states,FUN=function(x){
  df<-brazilcorona[brazilcorona$estado==x,]
  df<-df[order(df$obitosAcumulado,decreasing = T),]
  return(c(paste(x),as.character(df[1:2,"municipio"]),
           as.character(df[(nrow(df)-1):nrow(df),"municipio"])))})
```

I hope it helps you...